# How to JSON encode the data having HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a products data with products information. It's actually in form of array but I tried to use `json_encode` function to convert it into JSON response.

The problem is it has some HTML code inside product description so it's showing some lines.

Link : http://superwholesalebazaar.xyz/wocom.php

Why it's showing the lines ? Isn't it the JSON response ?

Thanks!

Comment: browser expect html so its doing its best to interpret it, you want to view source

Comment: You have `<del><span class=\"amount\">\u20b9` and it has some kind of `strike tag` that's why you're seeing the strike across the text. You need to use `strip_tags` function in php to get rid of all the html tags. Make sure to get rid of other characters to sanitize the data; as a result you'll have clean json data.

Comment: Just needed to add header('Content-Type: application/json'); Well thank you guys for your time  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its showing the lines because in the HTML part of the data you have  elements which naturally have the line strikethrough style associated with it such as the `<del>` element.

But since its a json response and you are sending it as a text/html type the browser renders it all as HTML and since json encode escapes some of the characters in the HTML its showing up a little weird such as some elements aren't closed properly.

I think what you want to do is send this response with the content type set to "json"

Here is how you can do this in php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// echo your json content here
```

Comment: that's a great idea.

Comment: Than you very much. Sorry but I cannot upvote or select your answer. :(

Comment: @MariaKari thats ok, you can select it though but it looks like you've figured that out ;)